# How to run TestNG test several times with BeforeTest execution?

Tags: java, testng

I try to execute the test several times with DataProvider.
All works fine, but `@BeforeTest` and `@AfterTest` execute only one time, but I need this execution with each iteration.:

```java
public class TestClass{

    @BeforeTest
    public void before(){
        Log.info("BeforeTest");
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void after(){
        Log.info("AfterTest");
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] tenTime(){
        return new Object[][]{
                {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}
        };
    }
    
    private static Integer c = 0;

    @Test(dataProvider = "tenTime")
    public void tenTimesTest(Integer count){
        Assert.assertSame(count, c++);
    }
}
```

- **Actual result:**
  `@BeforeTest` and `@AfterTest` executes once:

```
[INFO] 19-01-21 11:54:47 main | BeforeTest
[INFO] 19-01-21 11:54:47 main | The tenTimesTest test started
[INFO] 19-01-21 11:54:47 main | tenTimesTest test is starting.
[INFO] 19-01-21 11:54:48 main | The tenTimesTest test succeed
[INFO] 19-01-21 11:54:48 main | tenTimesTest test is passed
[INFO] 19-01-21 11:54:48 main | The tenTimesTest test started
[INFO] 19-01-21 11:54:48 main | tenTimesTest test is starting.
[INFO] 19-01-21 11:54:48 main | The tenTimesTest test succeed
[INFO] 19-01-21 11:54:48 main | tenTimesTest test is passed
..............
[INFO] 19-01-21 11:54:50 main | AfterTest
```

- **Expected result**
  `@BeforeTest` and `@AfterTest` executes each time with `tenTimesTest`:

```
[INFO] 19-01-21 11:54:47 main | BeforeTest
[INFO] 19-01-21 11:54:47 main | The tenTimesTest test started
[INFO] 19-01-21 11:54:47 main | tenTimesTest test is starting.
[INFO] 19-01-21 11:54:48 main | The tenTimesTest test succeed
[INFO] 19-01-21 11:54:48 main | tenTimesTest test is passed
[INFO] 19-01-21 11:54:50 main | AfterTest
[INFO] 19-01-21 11:54:47 main | BeforeTest
[INFO] 19-01-21 11:54:47 main | The tenTimesTest test started
[INFO] 19-01-21 11:54:47 main | tenTimesTest test is starting.
[INFO] 19-01-21 11:54:48 main | The tenTimesTest test succeed
[INFO] 19-01-21 11:54:48 main | tenTimesTest test is passed
[INFO] 19-01-21 11:54:50 main | AfterTest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow construction is suitable for me:

```java
    @BeforeTest
    public void before(){
        isBeforeTestExecutedFlag = true;
        method();
    }

    private void method(){
        Log.info("BeforeTest");
    }

    bool isBeforeTestExecutedFlag = false;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod(){
        if(isBeforeTestExecutedFlag){
             isBeforeTestExecutedFlag = false;
             return;
        }
        method();
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void after(){
        Log.info("AfterTest");
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] tenTime(){
        return new Object[][]{
                {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}
        };
    }
    
    private static Integer c = 0;

    @Test(dataProvider = "tenTime")
    public void tenTimesTest(Integer count){
        Assert.assertSame(count, c++);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use @BeforeMethod and @AfterMethod as following:

```
public class DemoTest {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoTest.class);

    @BeforeMethod
    public void before() {
        log.info("before");
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void after() {
        log.info("after");
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        log.info("test1");
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        log.info("test2");
    }
}
```

result:

```
before
test1
after
before
test2
after
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if you're using a data provider, your `tenTimesTest` is considered a single test, so `@BeforeTest` will only be executed once. If you need to execute it before every invocation you may try `@BeforeMethod`. Beware, though, that if you have more tests it will be executed as well

If you need some more fine grained execution control you may need to invoke the method by yourself from the test

You have more info [in the docs](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html)

Comment: I already have some tests and they are dependent on the `@BeforeTest`.